# How to bind user form input into view like results Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form in my application which when the users inputs it auto completes via a typeahead function with data from web api. What I want to do is once the user has made hi/her selection is to bind that selection into a further div where `{{si_id}}` will be as below. So far I have tried the following with no avail:

**html to bind to:**

```
 <div class="column col-12">
   <h6 class="tit text-bold">Serial Number</h6>
   <p class="text-small text-gray mb-5">{{si_id}}</p>
</div>
```

**Html form field:**

```
<div class="form-group mb-8">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
   <label class="form-label" for="si_id">Serial Number: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
   <ngb-highlight [result]="r" [term]="t">here</ngb-highlight>
</ng-template>
<input id="si_id" type="text" placeholder="Serial number" formControlName="si_id" class="form-input"
[ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" />
```

**ts file:**

```
public si_id = [];

private getSerials() {
    this.service.getSerials(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < data['result'].length; i++) {
        this.si_id.push(data['result'][i]);
    }
      console.log('Data' + data);
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('data is received');
    })
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getSerials();
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
      customer_id: new FormControl(this.customer_id),
      si_id: new FormControl(this.si_id[0], Validators.required),
      u_destination_country: new FormControl(this.u_destination_country[0], Validators.required),
      u_phone_number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_short_description: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(0),
        Validators.maxLength(80)
      ])),
      u_message_description: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

onSubmit() {
    if(this.serviceForm.invalid) {
       this.serviceForm.setErrors({ ...this.serviceForm.errors, 'required': true });
       return;
    }
    //this.loading = true;
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.postFormData(this.serviceForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response

    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear as to what is going wrong and what end state you’d like to achieve?

Comment: So where I have got {{si_id}}. Once the user has made their selection, it should bind to the html with {{si_id}.

Comment: So, you want to show the value of the si_id form control? FormControl has a `value` property, containing this value. So get the form control from your form group (you didn't post the relevant code, so we can't provide code either), and get its value.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the code. It all should be there now

Comment: So... `{{ serviceForm.get('si_id').value }}`? https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup, https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: That worked thanks, can you add as answer and I can accept it.